# como Resolver o erro nullReferenceExetion no Unity 3d

Tags: c#

Eu estava fazendo um jogo  de  tiro nightmare do unity traningday apareceu esse erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o codigo é esse

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;            // The position that that camera will be following.
    public float smoothing = 5f;        // The speed with which the camera will be following.

    Vector3 offset;                     // The initial offset from the target.

    void Start ()
    {
        // Calculate the initial offset.
        offset = transform.position - target.position;
    }

    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        // Create a postion the camera is aiming for based on the offset from the target.
        Vector3 targetCamPos = target.position + offset;

        // Smoothly interpolate between the camera's current position and it's target position.
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position, targetCamPos, smoothing * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Já tentou instanciar a variável?
'public Vector3 offset;'

Comment: eu sou novo com c# e nao sei instanciar

Comment: De acordo com a mensagem de erro, o problema está ocorrendo na linha 27 do arquivo de código fonte da classe **EnemyMovement*. Coloca por favor o código fonte dessa classe também na pergunta, @DanielCorreaSantos, e se possível destaca pra gente também qual é a linha 27, por que aqui no StackOverflow as linhas de código não ficam enumeradas.